# A way to "execute" only latex procedural code (\def, \let) in a sequence ignoring the rest?

Tags: macros, expansion

I have an external input file which I am reading line by line. This file contains text as well as some tex/latex macros. My goal is to write the content of this file into another external output file, and I would like to be able to replace some of the latex commands by symbols (to be more specific: I would like to be able to translate simple latex commands into their corresponding markdown counterpart).

So far, it works well for simple commands, eg \textbf{bold} is translated into **bold**. I have achieved this by redefining \textbf before writing back to the output file (I am using \write for this):

```
\def\textbf#1{*#1*}
```

Now I would like to be able to do the same for itemize. I would like the following code:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item one
  \item two
  \item three
\end{itemize}
```

to be translated into:

```
*   one
*   two
*   three
```

A first idea would be to ignore \begin{itemize} and \end{itemize} and simply redefine \item so that is expands into the markdown itemize prefix.

However, I want to be able to handle nested itemize. I have been using the same method (redefining \begin and \end, which in turn will use a modified \itemize and \enditemize), keeping track of the nesting level and increasing the markdown prefix accordingly. As you can imagine, things went wrong: since there is a lot of \def, \if, \begingroup etc. involved in the process, what I get at the end in my output file is a sequence of latex code, mainly containing \def's, braces, and so on.

This brings me to my question: before I send a line containing both text and "procedural latex code" (eg \def, \if and so on) to \write, is there a way to "execute" the procedural code it contains, and then write the output to the external file?

I have been using all the tricks I know (\edef, \expandafter's, \romannumeral, ...) to force the expansion, with no success so far.

This is a very minimal example to illustrate what I am trying to achieve:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{temp.tex}
This is \textbf{bold}

This is itemize:
\begin{itemize}
  \item one
  \item two
  \item three
\end{itemize}
\end{filecontents*}

\newread\filein
\newwrite\fileout

\def\markdownbf#1{**#1**}
\def\markdownbegin#1{\csname markdown#1\endcsname}
\def\markdownend#1{\csname markdownend#1\endcsname}
\def\markdownitemize{\edef\markdownprefix{*   }}
\def\markdownenditemize{}
\def\markdownitem{}
\def\markdownpar{}

\def\activatemarkdowncommands{%
  \let\textbf=\markdownbf%
  \let\begin=\markdownbegin%
  \let\end=\markdownend%
  \let\itemize=\markdownitemize%
  \let\enditemize=\markdownenditemize%
  \let\item=\markdownitem%
  \let\par=\markdownpar%
}

\def\translatefileA{%
  \begingroup%
    \edef\markdownprefix{}%
    \activatemarkdowncommands%
    \immediate\openin\filein temp.tex%
    \immediate\openout\fileout out.txt%
    \loop\unless\ifeof\filein%
      \immediate\read\filein to\fileline%
      \immediate\write\fileout{\markdownprefix\fileline}%
    \repeat%
    \immediate\closeout\fileout%
    \immediate\closein\filein%
  \endgroup%
}

\def\premarkdownbf#1{}
\def\premarkdownbegin#1{\csname premarkdown#1\endcsname}
\def\premarkdownend#1{\csname premarkdownend#1\endcsname}
\def\premarkdownitemize{\edef\storemarkdownprefix{*   }}
\def\premarkdownenditemize{\edef\markdownprefix{}}
\def\premarkdownitem{\let\markdownprefix\storemarkdownprefix}
\def\premarkdownpar{}

\def\postmarkdownbf#1{**#1**}
\def\postmarkdownbegin#1{\csname postmarkdown#1\endcsname}
\def\postmarkdownend#1{\csname postmarkdownend#1\endcsname}
\def\postmarkdownitemize{}
\def\postmarkdownenditemize{}
\def\postmarkdownitem{}
\def\postmarkdownpar{}

\def\activatepremarkdowncommands{%
  \let\textbf=\premarkdownbf%
  \let\begin=\premarkdownbegin%
  \let\end=\premarkdownend%
  \let\itemize=\premarkdownitemize%
  \let\enditemize=\premarkdownenditemize%
  \let\item=\premarkdownitem%
  \let\par=\premarkdownpar%
}

\def\activatepostmarkdowncommands{%
  \let\textbf=\postmarkdownbf%
  \let\begin=\postmarkdownbegin%
  \let\end=\postmarkdownend%
  \let\itemize=\postmarkdownitemize%
  \let\enditemize=\postmarkdownenditemize%
  \let\item=\postmarkdownitem%
  \let\par=\postmarkdownpar%
}

\def\translatefileB{%
  \begingroup%
    \edef\markdownprefix{}%
    \immediate\openin\filein temp.tex%
    \immediate\openout\fileout out.txt%
    \loop\unless\ifeof\filein%
      \immediate\read\filein to\fileline%
      \activatepremarkdowncommands%
      {\nullfont\fileline}%
      \activatepostmarkdowncommands%
      \immediate\write\fileout{\markdownprefix\fileline}%
    \repeat%
    \immediate\closeout\fileout%
    \immediate\closein\filein%
  \endgroup%
}

\begin{document}
  \translatefileB
\end{document}
```

If I use `\translatefileA`, then I get in `out.txt`:

```
This is **bold** 

This is itemize: 
\edef {* } 
one 
two 
three
```

If I use `\translatefileB`, then I get:

```
This is **bold** 

This is itemize: 

* one 
* two 
* three
```

The first version is wrong because `\markdownprefix` is not set as it should, because `\markdown\itemize` is not expanded as intended I guess.

The second version is ok. Unwanted output in the PDF file is deleted using \nullfont. So far it seems the best solution I could come up with.

Comment: Could you provide a MWE? Something that works for the simple `\textbf`, and what you want to work? Then we don't have to redo all of that :)

Comment: I suspect that you are asking the wrong question, but it is a bit hard to work out what workflow you are intending. You could look at (for example) ex4ht which is doing a similar job, but generating html rather than markdown

Comment: latex is a macro expansion language it doesn't really have procedural code, it isn't at all clear what you mean by executing code before you send it to a `\write`.  If the code is `\zzzz`  which has been defined by `\newcommand\zzzz{hello}` you can of course write `hello` (that will happen by default) but if it is `\hbox{hello}`  what do you want to `\write` `\hbox`, `{` and `}` are all non expandable primitives

Comment: What is the purpose? If you want to translate latex to markdown, there probably exists software for this. Also LaTeX is not a text manipulation program for sure. Searching and replacing substrings is one of the most hazzleful things you can do.

Comment: @David Carlisle: I suspect my question may have a simple answer. I do know that a lot of tex primitives (like \hbox you mentionned) are not suitable for my purpose, and I dont want to be able to translate them into markdown. What I do want is to be able to process some of them, like \textbf and the likes. The problem for me is to deal with \itemize so far.

Comment: @Andreas Storvik Strauman: the purpose is to generate a PDF file (as intended most of the time when using pdflatex) and also generate a python notebook with some markdown at the same time. I have been using this with colleagues to generate exercices for students: the python notebook contains code blocks and markdown. The PDF file contains additional info related to the notebook.

Comment: To ignore an environment, e.g. itemize, you can redefine the `\itemize` and `\enditemize` to ignore the `\begin` and `\end` and then redefine `\item`?

Comment: @Andreas Storvik Strauman: if possible, I would like to be able to ignore all possible output (not only what's between \begin and \end). At the same time, I would like all the commands to be "executed" (by that I mean that all the \def they induce take effect).

Comment: you can't do assignments in expansion only contexts such as `\write` and `\edef`, why can you not just discard the pdf, why does it matter if the pdf has junk so long as the correct text is run, you can use a second pdflatex run to generate the real usable pdf, in a run that doesn't generate the markdown

Comment: Actually I think I have found a solution: \nullfont. It seems \nullfont will disable output to the PDF file. So far it seems to work with my example, but I need to run a few more tests to check for potential undesired side effect.

Comment: `\nullfont` will make the current font blank, but of course any font change will change that, similarly any math will still be typeset. and rules etc but it is not clear why the pdf is an issue at all, or you could do the whole thing inside `\setbox0\vbox{....}` so nothing is output to pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems \nullfont answers my question, also it needs a little more work to handle math mode properly (see [\nullfont in mathmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61677/nullfont-in-mathmode)).

Below is the modified code to handle math mode (ie: suppress all output, yet expanding macros and defining them). Macro \translatefile will read the content of temp.tex, expand the macros it contains (first stage) without generating output in PDF, and translate it into markdown (second stage), generating file out.txt. It is not a fully functional translator, it is rather a proof of concept: it will only handle \textbf and (non-nested) itemize.

Node: another (and probably better) solution to achieve the same effect would be to use \setbox0\vbox{....} rather than \nullfont as David Carlisle suggested. However I'm not familiar enough with this kind of command to use it!

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{temp.tex}
This is \textbf{bold}, this is math: $1+x^2$.

This is itemize:
\begin{itemize}
  \item one,
  \item two,
  \item three.
\end{itemize}
\end{filecontents*}

\newread\filein
\newwrite\fileout

\begingroup
  \catcode`\ =12%
  \gdef\SPACE{ }%
\endgroup

\def\premarkdownbf#1{}
\def\premarkdownbegin#1{\csname premarkdown#1\endcsname}
\def\premarkdownend#1{\csname premarkdownend#1\endcsname}
\def\premarkdownitemize{\edef\storemarkdownprefix{*\SPACE\SPACE\SPACE}}
\def\premarkdownenditemize{\edef\markdownprefix{}}
\def\premarkdownitem{\let\markdownprefix\storemarkdownprefix}
\def\premarkdownpar{}

\def\postmarkdownbf#1{**#1**}
\def\postmarkdownbegin#1{\csname postmarkdown#1\endcsname}
\def\postmarkdownend#1{\csname postmarkdownend#1\endcsname}
\def\postmarkdownitemize{}
\def\postmarkdownenditemize{}
\def\postmarkdownitem{}
\def\postmarkdownpar{}

\def\activatepremarkdowncommands{%
  \let\textbf=\premarkdownbf%
  \let\begin=\premarkdownbegin%
  \let\end=\premarkdownend%
  \let\itemize=\premarkdownitemize%
  \let\enditemize=\premarkdownenditemize%
  \let\item=\premarkdownitem%
  \let\par=\premarkdownpar%
}

\def\activatepostmarkdowncommands{%
  \let\textbf=\postmarkdownbf%
  \let\begin=\postmarkdownbegin%
  \let\end=\postmarkdownend%
  \let\itemize=\postmarkdownitemize%
  \let\enditemize=\postmarkdownenditemize%
  \let\item=\postmarkdownitem%
  \let\par=\postmarkdownpar%
}

\newfont\dummyfont{dummy}

\def\translatefile{%
  \begingroup%
    \nullfont%
    \everymath{%
      \count0=0%
      \loop%
        \ifnum\count0<16%
        \textfont\count0\dummyfont%
        \scriptfont\count0\dummyfont%
        \scriptscriptfont\count0\dummyfont%
        \advance\count0 by 1%
      \repeat%
    }%
    \edef\markdownprefix{}%
    \immediate\openin\filein temp.tex%
    \immediate\openout\fileout out.txt%
    \loop\unless\ifeof\filein%
      \immediate\read\filein to\fileline%
      \activatepremarkdowncommands%
      \fileline%
      \activatepostmarkdowncommands%
      \immediate\write\fileout{\markdownprefix\fileline}%
    \repeat%
    \immediate\closeout\fileout%
    \immediate\closein\filein%
  \endgroup%
}

\begin{document}
  This should be visible.
  \translatefile %This should not be visible, only processed to out.txt
  This should be visible.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for a substring in the infile using `\readline`. `\readline` reads it as a raw verbatim input, and execute the line only if your commands are in there, if not the line is ignored. So there at two reads. Suffixed with ‘L’ for LaTeX to be run and with ‘V’ for verbatim (plain text)

*Edit*: Previous code not working. Now fixed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{substr, pgf, tikz}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newread\fileinL
\newread\fileinV
\openin\fileinL=inFile.dat
\openin\fileinV=inFile.dat

\gdef\executecommands{\string\xdef, \string\let}

\loop\unless\ifeof\fileinL%
  \readline\fileinV to\filelineV%
  \read\fileinL to\filelineL%
  \foreach \cmd in \executecommands{
    \IfSubStringInString{\cmd}{\filelineV}{\filelineL}{}
  }
\repeat%
\end{document}
```

Comment: this doesn't really address the question, as the OP wants to execute the `\def` without typesetting the text that is on that line not in the def.

Comment: Yeah, doesn’t really cover the case with multiple commands on one line.

Comment: I may have found a solution using \nullfont (see above). I will be running some tests to decide if it completely solves my problem.

Comment: Ah. I now got what you meant! Haha, okay. Then the answer I provided is pretty special casey! I was thinking you only wanted to run select commands, not that you wanted to run all commands, but suppress output.